# A simple overlay program

Tags: overlays

My buffer has one line as,

```
i am sitting on an overlay
```

Now when i do, `M-x some-function-to-hide`, i like to hide the text from display, and show three dots as,

```
...
```

I am looking forward to have a "hello world" program to understand overlays.

Comment: How about?:  `(overlay-put (make-overlay (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)) 'display "...")`

Comment: please, can you make this as answer... an extra info, i brought "..." back to original form using `(remove-overlays)`

Comment: How about?: `(remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max) 'display "...")`  I am at work today and won't have a chance to do an answer until later.  I'm not picky -- anyone can write-up an answer, even yourself if you are so inclined.

Comment: Please do some basic research before posting.  A [google search for "emacs overlay"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=emacs+overlay) yields the [manual page for "Overlays"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html).

Answer (score 2):

Reproducing lawlist's comments here,
     To make an overlay and minify the code block as "...", you can do,

```
(overlay-put (make-overlay (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)) 'display "...")
```

Now, to expand the contents and bring the buffer to its original form,

```
(remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max) 'display "...")
```